# Objective C: Is there a built-in way to count the total number of items in a 2d /nested NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a two dimensional  NSArray in Objective C.

I'd like to know the total # of items in the array.
Without using nested for loops, is there a faster way to get the total # of items?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-SW7

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, you can do this key-value coding and [the collection operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html):

```
NSArray *nested = @[@[@1, @2, @3],    @[@4, @5, @6],    @[@7, @8, @9],
                    @[@10, @11, @12], @[@13, @14, @15], @[@16, @17, @18],
                    @[@19, @20, @21], @[@22, @23, @24]];
NSLog(@"%@", [nested valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.@count"]); // logs 24 (as an NSNumber)
```

A couple of comments:

The key path `@sum.@count` works by first creating an array of the counts (so `@[@3, @3, @3, @3, @3, @3, @3, @3]`) and then summing up that array (to give `@24`).

However, this is only "faster" in the sense that *you* write less code. Fundamentally, it's still doing the same thing that you would be doing yourself. And it's potentially less efficient, because it's dealing with the addition of `NSNumbers`, which isn't as efficient as the addition of primitives (which you would likely be using).

Is it really that much more difficult to do:

```
NSUInteger total = 0;
for (NSArray *array in nested) {
  total += array.count;
}
```

Comment: You know, the obvious approach is not clever enough. And I'm sure it's not very efficient!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!